# How to define a block name in my SimuLink model?

Tags: matlab, simulink, simulink-library

Here in the simulink model, I can't define the block name with the equation. What is it called? How can I find it in the library browser?

I searched many blocks but couldn't find.

[image: diagram]

Comment: You can show block names in the Right Click > Format > Show Block Name > On. You can see the block info by double clicking it to see the properties pane, which will have the block type in the title bar of the window. Please clarify what you're stuck with

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the model. So I have to define the block just by looking at the image.

Answer (score 0):

The block you are looking at is the [`Fcn block`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/fcn.html), that applies a custom function to the input.